# Switch betweeen Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 screens: A, B, C.
From A, I use an Intent to switch to B and from B I switch to C.

How can I switch back to A from C (both C and B have to be destroyed and A is the screen that I was working on)?

Comment: By "screens", do you mean Activities?

Comment: Yes, I meant activities. In your opinion, what is the differences between "screens" and "activities"?

Comment: The difference is ***correct terminology***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two way:

1) start activity A again with clear stack in C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

2) you can start B and C for result and on in 'onActivityResult' close them:

for example in B when you want to start C

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,C.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
```

in C when you want to exit

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("should_exit",true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();
```

and in B (it is already behind C)

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            boolean shouldExit = data.getBooleanExtra("should_exit", false);
            if (shouldExit)
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the order of methods that'll get fired to get you back into A from C

```
A - startActivityForResult   
B - startActivityForResult   
C - finish()   
B - onActivityResult, finish()   
A - onActivityResult
```

Depending on if you need a result, just `startActivity` & `finish`